# glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT via remote desktop

Tags: windows, opengl, remote-desktop

I have an application that uses OpenGL. If I connect to a computer via Windows Remote Desktop I get an exception **"Extension function glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT not supported"** from my application.

I think the exception is caused because Remote Desktop does not support the extension.

My plan is to detect if the extension is available and skip rendering if not. The application is written in C# and uses SharpGL.

How can I detect in my application if the glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT extension is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glDeleteRenderbuffersEXT` is part of the extension [*GL_EXT_framebuffer_object*](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt). Retrieve the list of available extensions using `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` and check for the availability of `GL_EXT_framebuffer_object`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you btw know why exactly the rendering fails via Remote Desktop?

Comment: @anhoppe: Without some special software the Windows Remote Desktop is not using GPU acceleration. As such you're getting only the software rasterizer fallback which does not support any extensions and offers only a OpenGL-1.1 profile (could be OpenGL-1.4 on Vista or later, but I'd have to double check that) which does not have framebuffer objects (those got introduced only with OpenGL-3).